# how to reuse an image thats been loaded into Flash via AS3's loader()

Tags: actionscript-3, loader, reusability

I'm displaying an external image in Flash with the loader object, and then addchild() and that whole thing. Im wondering how, if possible, I could then add that same child to another movie clip. So far, when i do, it doesn't show up in the original movie clip anymore. Is there a way for me to display an image twice by pulling it from the same source like you would do with html,css?

Do i have to use the bitmapdata object for something like this? Im reading about it and I cant even see the purpose for it.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i have to use the bitmapdata object
>   for something like this? Im reading
>   about it and I cant even see the
>   purpose for it.

Yes, that's the way to go. Basically create a new `Bitmap` that uses the same `BitmapData`. Here's an example:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
load.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void {
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = event.target.content.bitmapData;

    // Now to make as many Bitmap instances as we want
    var bitmap1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
    var bitmap2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
    var bitmap3:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);

    // Use them for whatever you want here.

    // Cleanup
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
});
loader.load(new URLRequest('bitmap.png'));
```

Comment: Do you usually use inline functions for your event listeners? Wouldn't that make it difficult to remove the listener or create a weak reference?

Comment: @JoshuaSullivan: Nope, not really. I'll edit the code to show you how you can remove the event listeners.

Comment: Thanks so much. This feels like the right answer. I figured i had to go the bitmap route, but wanted to make sure there wasnt a way to just reuse a url path. thanks again.